# Use json overrides default argparse parameters

Tags: json, python-3.x, parameters, argparse

I have a argparse function containing a mix of internal and user specify settings. I want to use a json as configuration file to store user-specified parameters so that the json will be parsed back to this argparse function.

I also have a mix of data types in the parameters, they are defined in argparse but not in the json.

My argparse function looks like this

```
    def parse_opt():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('--name', nargs='+', type=str, default='experiment', help='project name')  #specify by users
        parser.add_argument('--visualise', action='store_true', help='output contains graphs')   #specify by users
        parser.add_argument('--imgsize', '--img', '--img-size', nargs='+', type=int, default=[640], help='image size h,w')  #let users specify
        parser.add_argument('--data', type=str, default=ROOT / 'data/coco128.yaml', help='(optional) dataset.yaml path') #internal default setting
        parser.add_argument('--thres', type=float, default=0.3, help='threshold')  #internal default setting
        opt = parser.parse_args()
        return opt
```

My json configuration `config.json` looks like this, and it allows users to specify their parameters

```
d = {"name": "trial_001", 
     "visualise": true, 
     "imgsize": 1280}
```

I tried the following to pass new configurations using the script below, and ran into error `TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable` . In the main() function, I want all default settings parsed as  `opt` , then the three use user-defined parameters defined in  `config.json` will override `opt.name`, `opt.visualise` and `opt.imgsize`. Then  `detect(**vars(opt))` reads all users and default parameters and apply `detect()` function to them (note: my `detect()` function isn't added in this post as it is quite long). Appreciate any pointers here. thanks.

```
import argparse
import json

def main(opt):
    opt = parse_opt()
    with open('config.json') as config_file:
        d = json.loads(config_file.read())
    for item in d.items():
        args.extend(item)
    detect(**vars(opt)) #detect() is a function that reads all variables from opt
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(opt)
```

EDIT: this is the full error message I encountered.

```
for item in d.items():
    args.extend(item)
    
parser.parse_args(args)     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-26-53a113868d66>", line 1, in <module>
    parser.parse_args(args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 1749, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 1781, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 1822, in _parse_known_args
    option_tuple = self._parse_optional(arg_string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 2108, in _parse_optional
    if not arg_string[0] in self.prefix_chars:
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Full error message (with traceback) please!  You/we need to figure out what variable is being indexed/subscripted, and is a boolean (but shouldn't be).  What is `args` in `args.extend(item)`?  I don't see it defined.  Output of `parse_args` is an `argparse.Namespace` object.  During debugging it's a good idea to display it.

Comment: The only code you need to show is the code where the error occurs - plus anything that clearly identifies the variables in the error.  There's nothing in the code you show that obviously would produce this error.

Comment: @hpaulj I have edit my post to include the error message.

Comment: sorry you're right that `arg` was a mistake, it was another dictionary object in my environment. This is the line I struggled with too but the aim was using `d` to override user settings in `opt`.

Comment: What is `args` when you call `parser.parse_args(args)`?

Comment: it's `args = {'help': 'Help message', 'required': True, 'name': ['-x', '--xvar'], 'imgsize':  640}`

Comment: That's not a valid input for `parse_args`.  Look at what the docs say about `argv`.  It should be a list of strings, similar to what the system gives you with `sys.argv`.

Comment: like this I believe.. `['help', 'Help message', 'required', True, 'name', ['-x', '--xvar'], 'imgsize', '640']`

Comment: `argv` can be something like `['--name', 'trial_001', '--visualize', '--img', '1280']`.  All of your parser arguments require flags.  In theory you could use the `json` data to set up a parser, that's more coding than I'm going to do for you.